# How to analyze a mastermind-like game using logical inferences

Tags: algorithm, set, logic

---

### DISCLAIMER: I am NOT looking for a solution to Mastermind.

---

I'm trying to write a program to solve a game like mastermind, and I'm a bit stuck. I don't want a full solution, only help with the part I can't get past. Here's the game:

There are `N` possible colors known in advance. There is an unknown set (possibly with repetitions) of `k` that are chosen and kept secret. The goal is to guess the colors (with repetitions) in the secret set. Let me emphasize again that this is a set, so *order does not matter*, but repetitions are allowed. For example

> Colors are `a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h` (`N=8`) and unknown set is `{a,c,c}` (`k=3`).

Successive guesses are made that result in more information about the secret set. Each guess must be a set (repetitions allowed) of `k` colors. The response to each guess is the number of colors in common between the guess and the unknown set counting repetitions. For example

> 1. Guess: `a,d,e`  Result: `1`
> 2. Guess: `b,c,f`  Result: `1`
> 3. Guess: `a,a,g`  Result: `1`
> 4. Guess: `a,c,h`  Result: `2`
> 5. Guess: `b,e,h`  Result: `0`

### The guesses are made by someone else. My objectives are:

### - Determine when information about a particular color is known.

### - Determine when the unknown set can be logically deduced.

At the start of the game, no colors are definitely in the set or definitely not in the unknown set (assuming `N>1`). After a guess that results in `0`, all of the colors of that guess are known not to be in the unknown set. If the result is `k`, then all of the colors of that guess are known to be in the unknown set. I'm having trouble writing a program to figure out all the cases in between. For example, nothing is known for certain about any of the colors until the last guess above. After the last guess, the set is known to be `a,c,c`.  The logic is this:

- By 5, `b,e,h` are not in the unknown set
- By 4, `a,c` are in the unknown set
- By 1, `d` is not in the unknown set
- By 2, `f` is not in the unknown set
- By 3, `g` is not in the unknown set
- Therefore the only colors in the unknown set are `a` and `c`.
- By 3, `a` is not in the unknown set more than once.
- Therefore the unknown set is `a,c,c`.

I can work through the logic this way, but I'm not sure how to program this in general. If someone could suggest a structured way to go about it, that would be great. ***I would prefer a high level explanation, with pseudo-code, rather than a full implementation in any one language.*** Thanks.

Comment: "interviewee": (hmm) Why do you need this and how quickly do you need an answer?

Comment: FYI, the term that you are looking for ("a set with repetitions, but unordered") is generally called either a [multiset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) or a bag.

Comment: @RBarryYoung I need it because I'm trying to write to learn how to implement logic in code, and this was the project assigned to me to do that. This isn't homework. I don't need it urgently, but it would be nice to keep making progress. I've spent a few days on this by myself, but I'm not finding a way to do it.

Comment: your choice of name is what begs this question.  I usually wait a while before helping someone with what appear to be interview questions, just as a matter of principle.

Comment: @RBarryYoung That was the user name I selected when I first signed up for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Straight-forward approach: Build the total population of possible combinations. Then, as guesses come in, remove the combinations that cannot possible satisfy the result for the current guess. Once you only have one combination left, that's the solution. Or, earlier in the process, when you no longer have a particular color represented then that one is (obviously) eliminated from the possible secret code.

Comment: I have two problems with this approach: 1. I don't know how to eliminate possible sets based on the combined guess/result information. 2. I cannot enumerate all possibilities easily since `N` can be quite large.

Comment: But +1 for being the first person to answer the question I asked instead of the one I explicitly didn't ask :-)

Comment: Oh! I get it. I can just compare the guess to the possible combination to see if they give the same result. So I suppose my only problem implementing this is point 2 - there are too many possibilities to enumerate. Still, this is a helpful suggestion. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can code up the logic after each guess as follows. Take an array of length `N`, where the entry of position `i` is `+1` if the `i`th color is in the set, `-1` if the `i`th color is not in the set and `0` if it is unknown whether or not the `i`th color is in the set.

After each guess, you create possible arrays satisfying the outcome. If a guess has result `r`, then there will be `(k choose r)` (or fewer if there are repeated colors) possible arrays. For your example, the arrays are (here I used `+` instead of `+1` and `-` instead of `-1` for brevity)

1. `(+,0,0,-,-,0,0,0) | (-,0,0,+,-,0,0,0) | (-,0,0,-,+,0,0,0)`
2. `(0,+,-,0,0,-,0,0) | (0,-,+,0,0,-,0,0) | (0,-,-,0,0,+,0,0)`
3. `(+,0,0,0,0,0,-,0) | (-,0,0,0,0,0,+,0)`
4. `(+,0,+,0,0,0,0,-) | (+,0,-,0,0,0,0,+) | (-,0,+,0,0,0,0,+)`
5. `(0,-,0,0,-,0,0,-)`

Now you can check for consistency among the possibilities as information comes in. There are 3 possibilities after the first guess, each equally valid. After the second guess there are 9 possibilities (1 of the first 3 and 1 of the second 3) and each is valid. After the third guess, there are 18 possibilities of which only 9 are valid. This is because the left option from 3 necessitates left option from 1 and conversely. After the fourth guess, there are 5 valid possibilities. After the fifth guess, there is only 1 valid possibility, namely:

1. `(+,0,0,-,-,0,0,0)`
2. `(0,-,+,0,0,-,0,0)`
3. `(+,0,0,0,0,0,-,0)`
4. `(+,0,+,0,0,0,0,-)`
5. `(0,-,0,0,-,0,0,-)`

Now the inclusion/exclusion of every color is known. You can handle multiplicities in a similar way.

Answer (score 0):

Knuth [described](http://www.dcc.fc.up.pt/~sssousa/RM09101.pdf) a solution. I [implemented](http://programmingpraxis.com/2009/11/20/master-mind-part-2/) it.

Comment: This is a solution to guessing. This does not solve the question I asked. In addition, I'm not concerned with positions.

Comment: To the OP: read the Knuth piece, and you will know how to guess.

Comment: @wildplasser ***I AM NOT LOOKING FOR AN ALGORITHM FOR HOW TO GUESS*** Please read my question. ***I AM NOT MAKING THE GUESSES***. I am only analyzing the information as it relates to the colors.

Comment: Well, decision trees or binary decision trees (oBDD) seem to fit well. Maybe with a little help from bitmasks to generate them. If you still have an unsolved game (which you seem to have) , the next decision to make is still what to try next ( :=will lead to the information you need)

Comment: @wildplasser You are still missing the question. ***I AM NOT MAKING ANY DECISIONS***. I am only trying to determine which colors are forced to be in the unknown set and which colors are forced not to be in the unknown set.

Comment: IMHO it is the same problem: understanding (or modelling) the structure of the problem (almost) equals determining which question to ask next (or even solving the question) It is all about understanding the topology of the problem. Deducing/restricting/declaring-predicates operates in exactly the same space as solving the question, or deciding what to do next. Modelling this space is solving *every* problem. Some people start by solving, others start by modelling. But they attack the same problem. From different angles. I still think an extension to BDDs comes very close to what you want.

Comment: @wildplasser Perhaps if you posted a concrete answer of your own he would understand what you mean. As this answer reads, it is clearly not answering his question.

Comment: I'll try to work something out, but it will take some time. BRB

Answer (score 0):

Selected items: ade=1 => 3 possibles 100, 010, 001

Unknown for this line: bcfgh=? => 5 items = 32 possibles

combine these to give 32*3=96 possible answers

repeat for next line and removing those that are not possible for all lines

till only one possible left

Comment: I appreciate that you're trying to help, but I don't understand that you've written here. Can you please add some explanation for what this is suppose to mean/do?